# Change base path of the generated migration files

Tags: python, django-1.7, django-migrations

In django 1.7, using the provided `makemigrations` command(not from South), is there a way to change the location of where the generated migration files are stored?

I'm keeping these files under version control and for apps imported from Django's contrib, they get generated right inside the app directory, which resides outside my project's root path.

For example, the `auth` app gets the files generated in this location in my case:

`/home/dev/.envs/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0002_group.py`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done via `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting.

In my case:

`MIGRATION_MODULES = dict([(app, 'migrations.' + app) for app in INSTALLED_APPS])`